# Why is the fragrant molecule linalool volatile when it has hydorgen bonding?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I've done a bit of research on volatile molecules and from what I've read, highly volatile molecules should have weak intermolecular forces (easy to go from liquid to gaseous state)....however it seems like the molecule linalool is an exception to this....I'm wondering if anyone can reconcile this contradiction (?) for me?

Comment: L. is not highly volatile. You should have searched for its boiling point (198 °C).

Comment: But isn't it the fragrant molecule in many flowers? Many of the papers I read said is was volatile...?

Comment: Perhaps you might ask why L. has a strong scent. It is volatile enough to reach our nose.

Comment: I was under the impression that molecules contributing to a strong scent are volatile...is this incorrect? Could you say that its pleasant scent is due to the relatively low volatility....so it's not overpowering...or am I oversimplifying?

Comment: Pls read comment above

Comment: Yes I did, but I'm still a bit confused. Are you saying that linalool is volatile...but only at a relatively low level?

Comment: I say that L. Is not highly volatile, at least much less than water so that there is no the contradiction you asked for. For why its concentration in air is enough for us to smell it should depends on its shape and interaction with our olfactory receptors. It is a completely different story. Don't make the equation smelling good (bad) thus highly volatile. All we need might be in a few ppm ranges.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll keep reading :)